# I am having difficulty reading this, help please?

Tags: перевод

Deleted deleted deleted deleted deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
лучшее видение ситуации. Я не хочу
ощущать то, что было в детстве
и переносить это зону (НЕ) комфор-
та во взрослую жизнь. Я достой-
на лучшего и я этого добьюсь.
```

Rough translation:

```
a better understanding of the situation. I don't want
to feel what I felt as a child
and transfer this (dis) comfort zone
into my adult life. I deserve a better 
life and I will achieve it.
```

Comment: At the risk of violating the code, translation added. :)

Comment: you, by all means, are not violating any code - answering question is fine in any case. The only danger is that sometimes we have to remove some questions and some reputation for an upvoted question could be lost.